# Saving pandas dataframe variable to csv from google compute engine to google storage bucket without saving to disk first

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a google cloud storage bucket called `google-storage-bucket-1`.

I'm connected my compute engine instance and I have a pandas dataframe variable which is created in python as a temporary variable called df1.

I want to save the dataframe as a csv file into the bucket. I use the following command.

```
import pandas as pd

df1.to_csv('gs://google-storge-bucket-1/test/dataframe1.csv')
```

But I get the following error,

```
OSError: Forbidden: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/xxx/o
Insufficient Permission
```

Whats the proper command to save the file to the bucket without saving it to disk first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import os
from io import StringIO

f = StringIO()  ## this is to avoid creating local file
df1.to_csv(f)
f.seek(0)

gcs = storage.Client()
gcs.get_bucket('google-storge-bucket-1').blob('dataframe1.csv').upload_from_file(f, content_type='text/csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

The above response created an error for me because of the encoding. Here's an alternative:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import os
from io import BytesIO

f = BytesIO()  ## this is to avoid creating local file
df.to_csv(f, encoding='utf-8', index=False)  # ensure UTF-8 encoding
f.seek(0)

gcs = storage.Client()
gcs.get_bucket('BUCKET_NAME').blob('FILENAME.csv').upload_from_file(f, content_type='text/csv')
```